# Obj-C - Tap gesture to return RGB color in imageview returning incorrect color?

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uitapgesturerecognizer

I'm using the below code to grab the RGB value of the point tapped inside an imageview (the imageview is a color wheel). Tapping the image works perfectly, and an RGB value is returned - however it's not the correct color. For example I tap the yellow area of the wheel, and a red RGB value is returned. Does anyone know what I'm missing/why this might be happening?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    UITapGestureRecognizer * tapRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGesture:)];
    [self.colorWheel addGestureRecognizer:tapRecognizer];
    self.colorWheel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
 
    
}

- (void)tapGesture:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint point1 = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(recognizer.view.bounds.size);
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    [recognizer.view.layer renderInContext:context];

    int bpr = (int)CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
    unsigned char * data = CGBitmapContextGetData(context);
  
    if (data != NULL)
        
    {
        int offset = bpr*round(point1.y) + 4*round(point1.x);
        int red = data[offset+0];
        int green = data[offset+1];
        int blue = data[offset+2];

        NSLog(@"%d %d %d", red, green, blue);
        
      
    }

    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pick `UIColor` in `self.view` with `CGPoint` from `UIPanGestureRecognizer` with correct `colorspace`**

```
@property (nonatomic) UIView *colorView; //preview of chosen colors
```

In implementation setup a recognizer and the image giving the colors we will choose from

```
UIPanGestureRecognizer * pan = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panGesture:)];
//pan.maximumNumberOfTouches = 1;
UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_overlap"]; //an Assets image
UIImageView *colorWheel = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
colorWheel.frame = self.view.frame;
colorWheel.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[colorWheel addGestureRecognizer:pan];
[self.view addSubview:colorWheel];

_colorView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50, 50)];
[self.view addSubview:_colorView];
```

catch the gesture location and set color of preview with chosen color.

```
- (void)panGesture:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {
    CGPoint location = [recognizer locationInView:recognizer.view];
    CGPoint p = { round(location.x), round(location.y) };
    _colorView.backgroundColor = [self colorInViewAtPoint:p];
}
```

find color in the self.view

```
-(UIColor *)colorInViewAtPoint:(CGPoint)p {
    unsigned char pixel[4] = {0};
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixel, 1, 1, 8, 4, colorSpace, (CGBitmapInfo)kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    // correct panlocation vs bitmapt coordintes
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, -p.x, -p.y);
    [self.view.layer renderInContext:context];
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
    return [UIColor colorWithRed:pixel[0]/255.0 
                           green:pixel[1]/255.0 
                            blue:pixel[2]/255.0 
                           alpha:pixel[3]/255.0];
}
```

even more simple than the solution before, have fun.

Comment: Oddly, this doesnt seem to work. No matter where I tap on the color wheel, the color comes out skewed. For example if I tap the solid grey in the center of the wheel, RGB values 0,0,0 are returned. If I tap a color, the 3 values returned always returns 255 as one of the values. Not sure what's happening :/

Comment: edited, so you see that colorspace and coordinates matter.

Comment: Oh this isss fun ha ha! Thank you so much, that is very helpful :)

Comment: That works swimmingly; that said, if I paste what you have in panGesture into my tapGesture, how can I pull the actual RGB values from it? Displaying the color itself works, but I can't seem to pull the values for use out :/ Pardon my newbness lol

Comment: that is because your code expects generic rgba but the format of views lay context is better done with kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast and the coordinates from point don't match CGContext coordinates. In other words, we made a mess :D

Comment: Lol! See edit to my comment (sorry, typing too fast!) Your method is way better - hands down. Ha ha. How can I pull the RGB values out for use? e.g. If I want to log them as I did in my original post?

Comment: and one hint after all.. you know that UIColor is inherited from NSObject so you can safely store all your chosen stuff in an NSArray and even write it out as plist or NSUserDefaults dictionary.. etc .. no need for string coversion into integers and back again.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218855/discussion-between-ol-sen-and-brittany).